# Definir tamanho de tabela responsiva

Tags: html

Estou criando uma tabela responsiva, só que quando estou numa tela grande, a tabela fica menor do que devia, tentei adicionar um `max-width` no *css* dela, só que mesmo assim não fica do tamanho proposto.

```
         <table bordered striped centered highlight responsive-table style="max-width: 500px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>001</td>
                    <td>Notebook i7 8GB Branco</td>
                    <td>Informática</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>002</td>
                    <td>Caneta Esferográfica Azul</td>
                    <td>Papelaria</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe está errada.
Falou declarar o `class` .

```
<table class="bordered striped centered highlight responsive-table" style="width: 90%; max-width: 500px;">
```